# Jquery Chosen plug in adds section on postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, jquery-chosen

I am using the Jquery Chosen plugin for an MVC application and everything loads properly initially. However, if i refresh a div on the page with data from the server using an ajax call it creates a whole duplicate section.

How do i prevent this from happening?

```
<div id="div1">
     <div id="div2">

     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-4">
         @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Id, Model.List.GetSelectionList(Model.Id, "Please select a Name to add."), new { @id = "id", @class = "chosen-select" })
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-1">
         <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add Name" onclick="AddName();" />
     </div>
 </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function AddName() {
    var id= $('#id').val();
    if (id> 0) {
        var url = '@Url.Action("AddName")';
        $.ajax(
            {
                type: "GET",
                url: '@Url.Action("AddName")',
                data: { id: id},
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#div2').html(data); //This is what duplicates the whole section
                },
                error: function (x, status, error) {
                    debugger;
                    alert(status + " " + error);
                }
            });
    }
};

var config = {
    '.chosen-select': {},
    '.chosen-select-deselect': { allow_single_deselect: true },
    '.chosen-select-no-single': { disable_search_threshold: 10 },
    '.chosen-select-no-results': { no_results_text: 'Oops, nothing found!' },
    '.chosen-select-width': { width: "95%" }
}
for (var selector in config) {
    $(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
}
```

Here is the initial load:

[image]

And here is after i click Add Name:
[image]

Comment: I forgot to add that the duplicate section only happens the first time i refresh the div. Anytime after that it does not create a duplicate section.

Comment: What is the content of "data"?  Proof of concept [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vrLfebt5/)

Comment: The content of the data was the whole partial page instead of just the section i was trying to update. That was causing the error

Answer (score 0):

This issue had nothing to do with chosen actually. I was updating the wrong div on the return of the ajax call. I needed to update the div for the whole partial view instead of just a section of it. Once i changed that it corrected the problem.